# How do you initialize a bitmap in kotlin(android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, tensorflow-lite, projects-and-solutions

Here's my code:

```
class Result : AppCompatActivity() { 
 
    private lateinit var select_image_button : Button 
    private lateinit var  capture_image: Button 
    private lateinit var make_prediction : Button 
    private lateinit var img_view : ImageView 
    private lateinit var text_view : TextView 
 
    lateinit var bitmap:Bitmap
```

Here's what I am getting as an error:

[image: Here's what I am getting as an error]

Comment: ``lateinit`` means you're not setting a value when the class is constructed, but you're promising that *by the time* something tries to read that variable, you *will have* set a value on it. You've got a click listener there trying to read the value of ``bitmap`` before you've actually assigned a ``Bitmap`` to it

Answer (score -1):

inside the onCreate function:

```
bitmap = Bitmap(1000,1000)
```

Comment: error occurs saying Too many arguments for public /*package*/ constructor Bitmap() defined in android.graphics.Bitmap

Comment: im sorry this is the right code: bitmap = createBitmap(1000, 1000)